# Focus on Input when DIV is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

Using React, I am trying to focus on an input element when certain buttons/elements are clicked. I need the ability to switch focus after render multiple times.

For example, If I click a name button, the name input box should focus. If I click the address button, the address input box should focus.

I'm familiar doing this with jQuery but it does not seem to behave as expected with React.js.

EDIT:

I am trying to use a button to open a menu. When the menu opens, I want the focus to automatically be on an input field.

I've tried the following:

```
willFocus(name) {
  if(name==='nameButton') {
  oDocument.getElementById('nameInput').focus();
}
```

- Using the label/for semantic. (Doesn't work because the label is not in the same form as the input.)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? do you have any code to showcase?

Comment: Please share some code, simple HTML showing your inputs. Will help with the rest.

Comment: I'm looking more to source ideas, however, I've tried making a function like the following `willFocus(elementID) { if element id==="nameButton" { document.getElementById("nameInput").focus() }`

Comment: I believe the semantically correct way to achieve what you're trying to do is by using the `label` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `ref` to the input field you want to be able to apply focus. I've named it `textInput`. I've used es6 syntax here.

```
<input
  type="text"
  ref={node => {
     this.textInput = node 
  }
}/>
```

Now you have reference to the node and can now access the input element from anywhere in the component.

To apply the focus in this input element, is as simple as `this.textInput.focus()`

Create a function that will apply the focus method to the node being referenced.

```
 handleMenuClick() {
   this.textInput.focus()
 }
```

Now you can call this function when someone clicks the menu button for example

```
<div 
 onClick={this.handleMenuClick.bind(this)}
> I AM MENU TITLE </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One very simple way is to use a `<label>` element:

```
<div>
<label for='input1'>Click here</label>
<input type='text' id='input1' />
</div>
<div>
<label for='input2'>Click here</label>
<input type='text' id='input2' />
</div>
<div>
<label for='input3'>Click here</label>
<input type='text' id='input3' />
</div>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kq3okzas/

Answer (score 0):

Use `label`. No javascript necessary.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 0):

You could use [The ref Callback Attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute). Taking an example of an input:

```
render() {
  // Use the `ref` callback to store a reference to the text input DOM
  // element in this.textInput.
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input }}
      />
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then, you are able to **explicitly focus** the input by:

```
this.textInput.focus();
```